# My "h" key intermittently fails, and it doesnt seem to be hardware related

Tags: macos

I'm using OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion) and a standard Apple keyboard.

Typing the "h" key intermittently fails and I can't figure out why. I replaced the keyboard yesterday, assuming that was the problem, but the issue persists with the new keyboard.

The bug is new since installing Mountain Lion, but I'm not positive that's when it started either -- I dont think it was -- and dont have any reason to suspect it's related.

A couple other notes:

- It's not limited to a specific application -- I've noticed it in at least Safari (textareas and the location bar), Colloquy, and Mail.
- The issue is occasionally accompanied by an alert/caution sound effect from OSX, but usually not
- I can't replicate it deliberately, but it happens many times per day in regular use.

The only hunch I have is that this was maybe a keyboard shortcut or text Substitution misfiring, so I've done the following:

- Audited "Keyboard Shortcuts" to see if maybe I mistyped something with an "h" in there
- Disabled any custom text substitutions
- Disabled autocorrect system-wide
- Turned off Alfred.app (to disable system-wide hot keys)

None of the above seem to have had any effect, and I'm not really sure where else to look to debug.

Comment: I repaired permissions using Disk Utility and so far that seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Repairing Permissions was a red herring -- I'm still having the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to show the virtual keyboard and see if it reacts to the keystroke? I've had a problem with a MacBook Pro where the key didn't react from time to time. This was a hardware error.

Anyway. The virtual keyboard will at least give you an idea if the keystroke goes into the OS as it should.

If you dont know where to find it: `Settings -> Input Sources -> Keyboard and Character Viewer`. Also add the `Input Menu` to menu bar for fast access.

Just a tip.